# Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I created a new React application by create-react-app and I wanted to write a unit test to a component named "MessageBox" that I created in the application. This is the unit test that I wrote:

```
import MessageBox from "../MessageBox";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

test('message box', () => {
   const app = {setState: jest.fn()};
   const wrapper = shallow(<MessageBox app={app}/>);
   wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click');
   expect(app.setState).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({modalIsOpen: false});
});
```

I also added a file under 'src' folder named 'setupTests.js' with the content:

```
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

I ran it by:

> npm test

and I got the error:

> Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but
>   found none. To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ > adapter: new Adapter() })`

Do you know what can solve this problem?

Comment: The current error message as of the date of this comment also has a URL to the documentation. Visiting that URL mostly explains what to do.

Comment: @CrazySynhax, please accept another answer from '@Mikel', cause it makes configuration shared and your tests will look more clear. Having such explicit configuration in each test is too verbose.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Add it to your test case file.

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
test('message box', ()=> {
     ...
})
```

Comment: This gave me `TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor`.  Had to change it to `import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';` before it would work.

Comment: what if you don't want to put this into every test?

Comment: Please update the answer with the first comment. So it will be helpful for others

Comment: This seems like something which ought to be put in to Enzyme as a "sensible default".   All of this configuration noise is exhausting.

Comment: Thanks! This actually helped me fix a different test :)

Comment: @MaxwellLynn You can create a setup.js file. Check the link.

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1265

Comment: If you make `setupTests.js` and put that in your src directory and add the enzyme configure it should work

Comment: Think the answer should mention that the `import` and `configure` needs to be put in the `setupTests.js`.

Answer (score 28):

Also, if you don't want to import your setupTests.js file into every test file, you can place it in your package.json folder:

```
  "jest": {
     "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/setupTests.js" }
```

Update:

```
Note: setupTestFrameworkScriptFile is deprecated in favor of setupFilesAfterEnv.
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: for people using creat-react-app, you don't have to make entry in package.json file. just create setupTests.js under src and it will be automatically picked. Also just ust import Adapter not * as Adapter

Comment: Here is more info supporting Priyank's comment:
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1265

Mikel gives an example src/setupTests.js file in another answer.

Answer (score 22):

The file 'setupTests' has to be imported to the test file:

```
import MessageBox from "../MessageBox";
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import "../setupTests"

test('message box', ()=> {
     ...
})
```

Comment: this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: This was the only thing working for me as well, but I noticed it only was an issue in Jest Runner extension for VS Code, so I found some configurations for it. See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66340321/7584643).

Answer (score 16):

As [Priyank said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222545/enzyme-expects-an-adapter-to-be-configured?rq=1#comment93749807_52951975), if you are using Create React App, it will pick up the configuration from `src/setupTests.js`.

Add:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

Comment: why we need Adapter, like in the official docs also they are telling use the adapter but why it is needed. Beginner to jest and enzyme . I don't know whether its a good question or not

Comment: For my case insteady of naming the configuration file as  "setupTests.js", I had named it as  "setUpTests.js". when I changed the name it worked.

Comment: This works. For Typescript projects it needs to have a .ts extension: src/setupTests.ts

Answer (score 10):

A lot of answers are saying import `setupTests.js` into your test file. Or 
configure enzyme adapter in each test file. Which does solve the immediate problem.

But long term, if you add a `jest.config.js` file to the project root. You can configure it to run a setup file on launch.

#### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"
}
```

This tells Jest to run setupTest.ts every time it's launched.

This way if you need to add polyfills or add global mock like localstorage, you can add it to your `setupTests` file and its configured everywhere.

The Enzyme docs don't cover integration with Jest, so it is confusing to fuse these two together.

Comment: This is what did it for me. I never even ejected my app from create-react-app, it just never picked it up!

Answer (score 7):

For me when using React with `create-react-app` I had to make sure the file name was correct. The file has to be `src/setupTests.js` with an `s` at the end of `Tests`.

Inside `setupTests.js` is the following:

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

When running `npm run test` it auto finds the `setupTests.js` file. There is no need to import it into each test file.

Comment: this works only when i put it inside `.test.js` file strangely not works when i put the same code in `setupTests.js` file added dependency `npm i enzyme-adapter-react-16 enzyme-to-json --save-dev` lets see

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the import like this:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```

This way: **(import * as Adapter from ...)** returns a message "TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor."

Answer (score 2):

Add `import React from 'react';` to the top of your file.

You are using JSX syntax `<MessageBox app={app}/>`, which [transpiles](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) into `React.createComponent(...)`. In order for this to work `React` variable must be defined in the scope of the file.

Comment: Thanks. But doing so, created another problem. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try sth like this;

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './containers/App';
import enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('App Screen', () => {
  let mountedAppScreen;
  let props;

  const appScreen = () => {
    if (!mountedAppScreen) {
      mountedAppScreen = enzyme.mount(
        <App {...props} />
      );
    }
    return mountedAppScreen;
  }
  it("it always renders div", () => {
    const divs = appScreen().find("div");
    expect(divs.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of the libraries, I've faced the same error reported in every answer of this question. Error: **TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor.**

I've grouped all the necessary steps in order to proper test your ReactJS component using Enzyme (*I've used Jest but it might work with Mocha as well, in that case, just switch the main test package*):

1) **Libraries (package.json)**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.6.0",
    (...)
}
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
   (...)
}
```

2) **TEST SETUP**: You can setup the Enzyme in every test. But as type_master_flash wisely suggested, you can add a script to do that. In order to do so, create a new setting in your package.json file at the same level of the sessions ***scripts, dependencies, etc***:

**Jest Version 23.x (or previous):**

```
"devDependencies": { 
     (...) 
 },
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./tests.setup.js"
 },
```

**After Jest 24.0 version:** According to [Jest Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array), "*setupTestFrameworkScriptFile is deprecated in favor of setupFilesAfterEnv*".

```
"devDependencies": { 
     (...) 
 },
"jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./tests.setup.js"]
 },
```

This file can be anywhere you prefer and you can name it as you wish. Just remember to setup the proper file location. In the current example I've stored my file in the root of my project.

3) **tests.setup.js**: As I've discovered in [Enzyme: TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824423/enzyme-typeerror-adapter-is-not-a-constructor), the problem here is that we cannot "***import*** '' *a module with a default export*". The proper way of configuring your file is:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Just that and you are good to test your components.

Cheers and hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure if 2) TEST SETUP is still viable. Least not if the React App is 'Out of the box'. You get errors like: `These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`

Comment: Well observed @Daedalus. I will update my answer with the latest version. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who reads this in the future, `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is deprecated in favor of `setupFilesAfterEnv` by the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array), in new versions. We can add our file like this:

```
"setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and for some reason React wasn't picking up `setupTests.js` file automatically.

I created a new file called `jest.config.js` at the root directory and added

```
{ "jest": { "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/path/to/your/file.js", } }
```

After this, error disappeared.

**Note:** Later on, I *removed* the `jest.config.js` file but it still works now.

Not sure what was actually causing the problem though!

Answer (score 0):

The file configuration must be in `setupFilesAfterEnv` property of `jest.config.js`

```
{
  ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.transform.js"],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this while trying to fix this after setting up Testing React Components with Jest in GatsbyJs (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/testing-react-components/)

In the `setup-test-env.js` you make, edit it to look like this:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named **setupTests.js** in the root of your project. jest will automatically look for this file before running any test suits. Add the following content to the file.

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({adapter:new Adapter()})
```

*Note: the filename should be exactly the same.no need to import this setupTests.js file into your test files.it will work automatically*

Answer (score 0):

For those who use VS Code and the Jest Runner extension for a React CRA app, don't forget to [configure Jest Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firsttris.vscode-jest-runner#usage-with-cra-or-similar-abstractions) to use CRA's built in script runner by setting the jest command to:

*npm test -- --watchAll=false*

You will get the error in topic if you forget to do that. And since you are using CRA you won't be able to configure *setupFilesAfterEnv* in package.json nor jest.config.js. Trying that will result in this error:

*These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App*

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm i enzyme-adapter-react-16 enzyme-to-json --save-dev`
2. Add to `package.json`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHbe0.png)

```
"jest": {
       "collectCoverageFrom": [  "src/**/*.js", "!src/index.js" ]
};
```

3. Add two files to src folder ->

- `setupTests.js`
- `tempPolyfills.js`

4. `setupTests.js` :

```
import requestAnimationFrame from './tempPolyfills';

        import { configure } from "enzyme";
        import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

        configure({adapter: new Adapter(), disableLifecycleMethods:true});
```

5. `tempPolyfills.js`:

> ```
> const requestAnimationFrame = global.requestAnimationFrame = callback => {
>           setTimeout(callback,0);
>       };
> export default requestAnimationFrame;
> ```

6. in case shallow -> expect() fails in test case use toJson() :
   Example :

```
    import { shallow } from "enzyme";
    import App from "./App";
    import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
    describe('App', () => {
        const app = shallow(<App />);
        it('renders correctly', () => {
            expect(toJson(app)).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think you've otherwise setup everything correctly (e.g. have the @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 for React 17 support installed), one more pitfall to check with Typescript:

Do you have

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

and the matching import format for the adapter?

```
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
```