# failed to test Container although setup for enzyme successfully

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have this container

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.changeInput} />
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Why can't I use `shallow` on it? My test looks like so

```
import App from "./index";

describe("App", function() {
  it("should render", function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    //expect(wrapper).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

The error says `Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.` but I believed I've setup Enzyme correctly. I want to test whether App contain input and a button, but I'm stuck there..

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/21rz901mp0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222545/enzyme-expects-an-adapter-to-be-configured)

Answer (score 0):

Just install this package `enzyme-adapter-react-16`, and in your tests add those two lines :

```
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one enzyme.js file and add follwing code...
And import it into test unit-test case file

```
import Enzyme, { configure, shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
export { shallow, mount, render };
export default Enzyme;
```