# Jest and Enzyme configuration is not properly working my React/Typescript Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

Some thing went wrong when I start `npm test`.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.19",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.12",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/path/to/setupTest.js"
  }
}
```

Here is `my-app/jest.config.js`

```
// For a detailed explanation regarding each configuration property, visit:
// https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

module.exports = {
  // Automatically clear mock calls and instances between every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // An array of glob patterns indicating a set of files for which coverage information should be collected
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"],

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // An array of file extensions your modules use
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "jsx"],

  // The paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment before each test
  setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/enzyme.config.js"],

  // The test environment that will be used for testing
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",

  // The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files
  testMatch: ["**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)"],

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["\\\\node_modules\\\\"],

  // This option sets the URL for the jsdom environment. It is reflected in properties such as location.href
  testURL: "http://localhost",

  // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/"],

  // Indicates whether each individual test should be reported during the run
  verbose: false,
};
```

here is `my-app/setupTests.ts`

```
/** Used in jest.config.js */
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

here is my test case `Header.unit.test.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Header from "./Header";

describe("Header Component", () => {
  it("It should be render without errors", () => {
    const component = shallow(<Header />);
    console.log(component.debug);
    const wrapper = component.find(".headerComponent");

    expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

And here is the error that I am encountering, when running the test:

```
  Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.
  To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
  before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
  corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:
```

Comment: React Scripts 4 comes with React Testing Library set up, why not use that instead of Enzyme? Also note that React Scripts uses its own configuration for Jest, which IIRC does include **`src/`** `setupTests.ts`, but then you've tried to override that with `"<rootDir>/enzyme.config.js"` anyway. Does your config get loaded? Does the `setupTests` file?

Comment: I think you can find answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222545/